# Sympy is returning multiple answers despite specifying positive answers only

Tags: python, sympy, simplify

after specifying:

```
KEQ1,KEQ2,KEQ3,H2O, CO, CO2, H2, CH4  =s.symbols('KEQ1,KEQ2,KEQ3,H2O, CO, CO2, H2, CH4',positive=True)
~6 equations that I can't share~
s.nonlinsolve(functions,variables)
```

Sympy solves for H2O, CO, CO2, H2, CH4 properly and leaves them in terms of H2O and the KEQs, which is expected since two of the equations are linearly dependent. I know the KEQs and substitute them in.

**However** Sympy is returning two sets of solutions. I specified that all of the variables are positive. I don't know why this is, since it should be able to simplify any square roots based on the positive condition. If I can narrow it down to 6 linearly dependent equations I can just solve it numerically within an acceptable tolerance.

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you provide those 6 equations? Providing them may help others while answering.

Comment: I believe it's considered confidential information for my job

Comment: Honestly, if your work is so sensitive that it cannot be shared on StackOverflow, then you probably shouldn't be asking this question. Depending on your company's policies, it could be seen as a risk.

Answer (score 0):

A simple test shows that `nonlinsolve` does not pay attention to the attributes of the symbols:

[image]

So you will have to filter your results by hand.

Note, too, that you can use `nsolve` to solve a system of equations.

Comment: Thank you very much. nsolve wasn't working for me but maybe I haven't played around enough with its input options yet.